# What's the use of the hexagon bottom in braisers?

Tags: cookware, cast-iron

I have a few cast iron skillets and a dutch oven and I want to get an enamelled cast iron pan so that I won't have to worry about ruining the seasoning when using acidic sauces (tomatoes, lemon, etc).

I like [this shallow Staub pan](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71v34auKv5L._SL1500_.jpg) but I'm not convinced about the hexagon shapes. They say the hexagon bottom produces a natural non stick surface that is more resistant to scratches and chips. Has anyone used something similar to this or know what the hexagon shapes at the bottom are for?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern on the bottom is to reduce sticking, as food is only likely to stick to the peaks and not the valleys.

It is also intended, with dubious effectiveness, in my mind to extend the non-stick lifetime of the pan as the non-stick coating tends to only wear off the peaks, and not so much from the valleys.

In my mind,  non-stick is not a feature I would look for in a dutch oven, where you want fond development for braises and searing.